# Deploying custom Docker image w/ gunicorn causing non-reproducable errors on Heroku

Tags: heroku, docker

**TL;DR** I'm attempting to deploy snekbox via a docker image to Heroku, it seems to have issues installing requirements (especially gunicorn).

The specific repo I'm attempting to install is snekbox: https://github.com/python-discord/snekbox

**Description of the issue**
When attempting to push a Docker image of snekbox, which contains a Dockerfile with requirement installation code to Heroku, I'm constantly faced with `ModuleNotFoundError` when the code trys to import Gunicorn, even though it's part of project requirements. Running this image locally is absolutely fine, so it must have something to do with how Heroku handles docker images. The requirements are installed using `pipenv` using the default Dockerfile.

Building, pushing, and releasing the docker image all runs normally in Heroku, until the Dyno attempts to boot up which results in said `ModuleNotFound` error.

**What I've tried**
I've tried a number of things, including:

- Using docker tag to directly push the pre-built image from GitHub Container Registry to Heroku
- Downloading the source code and building it myself normally using docker then pushing/releasing to Heroku
- Downloading the source code and building it myself using `heroku.yml` then pushing/releasing to Heroku
- Changing `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` to `requirements.txt` and not touching anything else
- Changing `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` to `requirements.txt` then editing `Dockerfile` (I didn't end up figuring this out, so so many errors as I'm inexperienced with Dockerfile)

I'm not sure where to go from here as I've run out of ideas. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could explain why this is happening and/or how to fix it. I'm also open to suggestions for other hosting services to run snekbox on, free is preferred but at this point I'm fine with paid hosting just to make my life easier.

---

Possibly related StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68948252/how-can-i-host-snekbox-on-heroku